# xsim: clear-aux option causes error

Tags: xsim

Since today, I got an error when trying to compile a document with the `xsim` package and its `clear-aux` option.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
    clear-aux
}


\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

On my machine this generates the following error:

```
LaTeX3 Error: The key 'xsim/clear-aux' is unknown and is being ignored. }
```

This was previously not the case. I don't exactly know what changed, because I'm using two different machines. It compiled fine on both machines before though, that's why I'm confused.
The `xsim` version is 0.16a and I'm using MiKTeX v. 2.9.7250 on Windows. My editor is texstudio.

I'll try reproducing the error on the other machine as soon as I have access to it again, but maybe someone already has an idea what may cause this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the manual for `xsim` v. 0.16a, it appears that the options have been reorganised. Instead of

```
\xsimsetup{
    clear-aux
}
```

it should now be

```
\xsimsetup{
    package/clear-aux
}
```

Comment: Or `\usepackage[clear-aux]{xsim}`

Comment: It appears, that my reply doesn't work anymore, at least not universally. The way in @cgnieder's comment does, though.
With MiKTeX, everything is fine, but with TeXLive on Linux, I get the error ```Package xsim Error: `clear-aux' is a load-time option!(xsim) You need to use \usepackage[clear-aux]{xsim}. }```